# Hide whole code block and only show fragments or jump to the first fragment

Tags: gitpitch

I am creating a presentation about some Java stuff and I want to show some code.

I have the problem, that I want to present Java code and the first snippet is the import block if I use the Code Delimiter Slides.

If I use the Code Block Slides, the whole code shows up. This will distract the audience.

Is it possible to jump to the first fragment in a code block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to jump to the first fragment in a code block?

The answer is no, it is not currently possible.

GitPitch code-presenting gives you a way to *step-into* any code block, source file, or GIST. But the starting point is always as if you just opened the source code in your editor (you see the contents of the block, file, GIST).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to add a transition with a second click so it jumps to the first fragment? This maybe a 'ok' workaround. The problem is, that Java code have too much import statements on the top, so it looks not nice.

Comment: Adding an auto-transition to skip the initial code slide is not currently supported.